# Smooch - Get message returning Invalid key id (kid)

Tags: json, get, jwt, smooch

I'm trying to run a HTTP get request in order to get messages from my facebook messenger channel that I have integrated with my smooch app. All I'm doing is a GET request to https://api.eu-1.smooch.io/v1/apps/app_id/appusers/user_id/messages with an authorization header, which is "Bearer app JWT". The result of this is the following,
    {
  "error": {
    "code": "invalid_auth",
    "description": "Invalid key id (kid)"
  }
}

The key id and secret have been taken from the app settings page on the smooch website. The JWT was made up of the following,

i) "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "kid": "key id from app"
ii) "scope": "app"
iii) HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  app secret)

Any ideas on what I could check or from what you can see is there anything obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Invalid key id (kid)` means that your key doesn't exist or your app could not be found. I notice in your URL that you are hitting the EU region (`https://api.eu-1.smooch.io`), is your application created in EU or US? I would suggest to try hitting the US endpoint `https://api.smooch.io` and it will likely solve your problem

Comment: I can confirm that this change has fixed the issue! Thanks!